# How to get html elements to load with different classes depending on JavaScript variable?

Tags: html

I made a dark mode for a site where when the site loads, the code goes through and adds or removes classes depending on which theme you set it to the last time you used the site (saved using localStorage). While it works, whenever you load the page or go to another page in the site there is a flash of white, as it loads the default theme (light) before the script is run changing it to dark. If I link the script at the top of the document the only object getting the dark theme applied is the body element, as it is the only element that has been loaded when the script is run. How can I make it so that the html elements are loaded initially with the correct classes (as saved in the browser) so that I don't get the white flash before the script is run? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just change the body tag className and have your theme dependent on child of body.themename?

Comment: To get rid of the flickering, make sure that the JavaScript is loaded before the page - it's best in the HTML head in this case. But I thin k @MosheSommers is suggesting the right approach in the comment before.